# Scraping specific javascript variables from HTML using python requests

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am currently making a GET request on python, and in the response it returns a few specific variables that I need to extract and "save" as variables in my code for future use in the code.

The variables are called accessToken, ivString, and fpAccountId. Each of them are equal something and that is what I need to extract.

Here is how it looks in the GET request response HTML:

```
var accessToken = "8CULRLPATAMoPf3fIRKJ7D13e3Dtchruqu=";
var ivString = "2e84726625315acjfshfsf==";
var encryptedFpAccountId = "NArzA4fzqrskjfs6sf==";
```

These are the 3 that I need. The code that I have so far has been using Beautiful Soup to extract the HTML but I am unsure of how to get these values into a simplified version so I can use the variables in my future code. Here is what I have so far using beautiful soup to get the response:

```
uSoup = BeautifulSoup(b.text, 'html.parser')
data = uSoup.find_all('script')[16].string
```

b is the resonse

Comment: And what is the content of `data`?

Comment: Use a headless browser instead and read the variables and the dom elements using javascript

Comment: the content of data is the HTML response from the GET request that has the variables in it. @JohnGordon

Comment: I need to use requests because of my certain situation @charlietfl

Comment: A headless browser makes a request and allows you to parse the response using javascript to pass to your python

Comment: yeah but these variables are unique on each request and I need to maintain the variables in the session in order to keep using them @charlietfl

Comment: not sure you understand what a headless browser is. It runs server side and interacts with your server side language

Comment: i know what a headless browser is, if I could have used it in this instance I would... I dont think you understand what I'm trying to do

Comment: Could you provide us with a URL or the content of `data`? Is the only problem you have reading these variables from a `data`?

Comment: Either the complete `<script>` string, or the URL is needed to help you further.

Comment: how would I use the URL? I have it but don't know what to do with it for this @Jatimir

Comment: @abs11 you have to use it to obtain the html code. Just add it to your question so we can see the page, you are trying to scrape these variables from.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can get value of the accessToken, ivString and encryptedFpAccountId is by using the slice operator on data you get and clipping the value of these variables by hit and try and getting the slice values e.g data[10:40] for accessToken